# How to get a difference in hours(decimal) from HH:MM formats in google sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets, format

I wish to get a difference in hours from `HH:MM - HH:MM` in a decimal format, applying to multiple rows (an `ARRAYFORMULA`).

For example:

```
13:30 - 11:00
```

Which would result in `2.5` hours.

How do I achieve that?

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I tried with `=INDEX(SPLIT(C10, ":"), 1) + (INDEX(SPLIT(C10, ":"), 2)/60) - INDEX(SPLIT(B10, ":"), 1) + (INDEX(SPLIT(B10, ":"), 2)/60)`, but it doesn't calculate well when you put in `21:50 - 20:50`. The result is `2` hours (in decimal), which obviously is not ok.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z4Mo97Fu11_y_9DbgjnkuBH6EKjChpGEtMrFb3TIRg4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(24*ABS(
 INDEX(N(SPLIT(A1:A, "-")),,2)-
 INDEX(N(SPLIT(A1:A, "-")),,1))))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,24*ABS(N(C2:C)-N(B2:B))))
```

[image]